# post to wordpress with CURL

Tags: php, wordpress, post, curl, xml-rpc

I tried to post to wordpress blog from extrnal php code , all of my files are in the same directory, public_html.

this is my code:

```
function wpPostXMLRPC1($title,$body,$rpcurl,$username,$password,$category,$keywords='',$encoding='UTF-8') {
$title = htmlentities($title,ENT_NOQUOTES,$encoding);
$keywords = htmlentities($keywords,ENT_NOQUOTES,$encoding);

$content = array(
    'title'=>$title,
    'description'=>$body,
    'mt_allow_comments'=>0,  // 1 to allow comments
    'mt_allow_pings'=>0,  // 1 to allow trackbacks
    'post_type'=>'post',
    'mt_keywords'=>$keywords,
    'categories'=>array($category)
);
$params = array(0,$username,$password,$content,true);
$request = xmlrpc_encode_request('metaWeblog.newPost',$params);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $rpcurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
$results = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $results;
}
```

but its wrong, the error is

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function xmlrpc_encode_request()
```

i can post to my wordpress blog with microsoft word(publish->blogPost), so Help me

Comment: and what cant you understand, the requested `xmlrpc_encode_request` function is not installed or activated on server.

Answer (score 2):

PHP's xmlrpc extension seems to be not enabled on your server.

Comment: but i can send blogpost with microsoftword(publish->blogpost), it use xmlrpc for send post

Comment: I installed xmlrpc on my server now, and tyied again but show me same error Fatal error: Call to undefined function xmlrpc_encode_request()

Comment: Did you reload the server configuration? Can you see the _xmlrpc_ extension in the output of phpinfo()?

Comment: Apparently, the extension is not loaded.

Comment: Depends on your server configuration/distribution/etc

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress using http://scripts.incutio.com/xmlrpc/ as xmlrpc server, you don't need xmlrpc extension to post to your wp. Just follow the instruction http://scripts.incutio.com/xmlrpc/advanced-client-construction.php.

But if you want to post on another way, such as posting by email you can follow this tutorial codex.wordpress.org/Post_to_your_blog_using_email

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same. I found a similar problem somewhere else on the net and tweaked to to fit Wordpress. Mind you Wordpress install (wordpress.org), not the blog hosting service at wordpress.com. This should be working provided you have curl and xmlwriter enabled:

```
<?php
class atompub
    {

    //public $parae = '';

    function __construct($one, $two, $three, $four)
        {
        $this->author=$one;
        $this->title=$two;
        $this->categories=$three;
        $this->body=$four;
        }

    function create_post() 
        {
        $xmlwriter = new XMLWriter();
        $xmlwriter->openMemory();
        $xmlwriter->startDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
            $xmlwriter->startElement('entry');
                $xmlwriter->writeAttribute('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');
                $xmlwriter->startElement('author');
                    $xmlwriter->writeElement('name', $this->author);
                $xmlwriter->endElement();
                $xmlwriter->writeElement('title', $this->title);
                $xmlwriter->startElement('content');
                    $xmlwriter->writeAttribute('type', 'html');
                    $xmlwriter->text($this->body);
                $xmlwriter->endElement();
                $xmlwriter->startElement('category');
                    $xmlwriter->writeAttribute('term', $this->categories);
                $xmlwriter->endElement();
            $xmlwriter->endElement();
        $xmlwriter->endDocument();

        return $xmlwriter->outputMemory();
        }

    function __destruct()
        {
        }
    }


$target = "<URL til your WordPress installation>/wp-app.php/posts";  
// Note that the directory "posts" are used for posting (POST method)
// "service" is used to pull info via the GET method (not shown here)

$user = "XXX";  // Substitue XXX with your WordPress username
$passwd = "YYY";   // Substitue XXX with your WordPress password

$author='Your Name';
$title='The title of your choice for your new entry';
$array_of_categories='Category';
$body='This is the main body. All the text goes in here';

$xml_post = new atompub($author,$title,$array_of_categories,$body);
$post = $xml_post->create_post();

$headers = array("Content-Type: application/atom+xml ");
$handle = curl_init($target);
$curlopt_array = array(
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
CURLOPT_POST => true,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $post,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
CURLOPT_USERPWD => $user.':'.$passwd,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT => true);
curl_setopt_array($handle, $curlopt_array);

$result = curl_exec($handle);
//var_dump($result);
$header_sent=curl_getinfo($handle);
//var_dump($header_sent);

if ($result === false) {
print "Got " . curl_errno($handle) . " : " . curl_error($handle) . "\n";
curl_close ($handle);
return;
}

$response_http_code = curl_getinfo ($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ($response_http_code != 201) {
print("HTTP status code: $response_http_code \n");
curl_close($handle);
return;
}

curl_close($handle);

?>
```

This should work directly, but you need to change the strings indicated (Blog URL, username, password, author, etc...). Beware that the login in insecure. This is only for demonstrating the functionality. You may also want to change the response code handling (which isn't mine, it came along with the original example which this is based upon).

On success Wordpress returns XML to you with details of the post event.

Comment: This example is using the Atompub protocol, which seems to be for text only (not binary). I might be wrong, but I am pretty sure. This have nothing to do with Curl per se, but the fact that the receiving end (Wordpress) is expecting an XML input with very specific tags.

Answer (score 0):

Fatal error: Call to undefined function xmlrpc_encode_request()

some times this error appear because xmlrpc extension is disabled.

execute phpinfo() to see if xmlrpc module displays or not.

If not, you need to enable it from php.ini by removing the semicolon, like

;extension=php_xmlrpc.dll to extension=php_xmlrpc.dll

and then restart Apache